# Can't get filesize() from 20 Mb file

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

I'm setting an application that reads information from a ts video file. If the file is 10 Kb, he function works perfectly, but when the file is much longer (around 20.478 KB) it gets frozen, and I can't get any information. No filesize(), neither files() or anything. I tried almost everything but I'm out of ideas.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Proyecto</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="leerBytes.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Choose a file: <br>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send" onclick="post"> <br>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code: (leerBytes.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["button"])){

    echo "File sent  <br>";

    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    echo "<br>";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode ('.',$fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));


    $allowed = array('ts');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {

        if($fileError === 0){

            $fileNameNew = uniqid('',true).".".$fileActualExt; 

            $fileDestination = 'uploads/' .$fileNameNew;

            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

            $byte = new leerBytes();
            $byte ->leerByte($fileDestination);
        }else{
            echo 'Error.';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Wrong file.';
    }
}

class leerBytes{
    function leerByte($file){
        $filesize = filesize($file);
        echo $filesize;
        $fileopen = fopen($file, "rb") or die("Can't get fileopen");
        $bytesize = 8;
        if($fileopen){
            $header = null;
            $body = null;
            echo "There's data";
            $buffer = fgets($fileopen, 4096);

            echo $buffer;

            fclose($fileopen);
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I expect to get the filesize, or the information from the file in an array.
I leave here some files as example: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Hge4w8cIZBRm3TskABWcQZSoFFVUMx0-?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe you're exceeding PHP's [`upload_max_filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Comment: i wonder what would happen if i upload a `backdoor.php\0.ts` file on your server as `move_uploaded_file()` is not on all PHP versions safe against NULL bytes related attacks.. `move_uploaded_file()` would make a file `backdoor.php` then if the PHP version is vulnerable.

Comment: @Barmar I changed the upload_max_filesize to 1GB...

Comment: @RaymondNijland Using any user data in the filename itself is extremely risky, and you're right here to watch out for file extension attacks.

Comment: *"Using any user data in the filename itself is extremely risky,"* indeed @tadman  i also very much agree on that..